# And in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

Is it possible to have and(&&) in freemarker or do I have to use a nested if?

```
<#if object?exists >


</#if>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use && as logical operator in free maker. See [Logical operations](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_logicalop)

For example

```
<#if x < 12 && color = "green">
  We have less than 12 things, and they are green.
</#if>
<#if !hot> <#-- here hot must be a boolean -->
  It's not hot.
</#if>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use OR logic operator

<#if color == "blue" || color == "green">
  We have less than 12 things, and they are green.